# Python Django POST issues

Tags: python, django

I am facing a problem with posting data in Django.

I have defined one URL in urls.py:

```
  url(r'^lares_conf_123kmk_$', 'lares.call_sta.my_func', name='home'),
```

My function is my_func is defined as:

```
def my_func(request):
   u = request.POST.get("parsed_news", "")
   p2 = re.compile("(VP+)\\s[(+](\\w+)\\s(\\w+)[)+]")
   my_sent = u.split("##")[:-1]
   zeta = []
   for sent in my_sent:
     m = p2.findall(sent)
     if(len(m)>=0):
         zeta = zeta + m
   return HttpResponse(str(zeta), content_type="application/x-javascript")
```

Now I am calling the above mentioned url like following:

```
 import requests

 payload = {"parsed_news":"Hello World"}
 response = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8080/lares_conf_123kmk_", data=payload)
 print response.status_code
```

But I am unable to POST any data. And the status is constantly showing 403.

Kindly help.

Comment: Did you try to google "Django 403" to see why it might be returning that code? It's a very very common issue.

Comment: @DanielRoseman  sorted. Yes I totally forgot about csrf! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks to me like you're falling foul of Django's [Cross Site Request Forgery protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/).

You can test that theory by marking the view as exempt, using [`csrf_exempt`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt). This is probably not a good idea for production (you probably want CSRF protection turned on), but should allow you to identify the problem.

Comment: My bad, I totally forgot about the csrf actor. Done! Thanks man.